# Wordpress - Multiple categories in a category page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem on my category template. I use the function `get_the_category()` to get the current category of the page.

I take the first one of the array to select the posts and show in my custom menu the current category.

It works well for all my categories except for one. 
In this category (which is exactly the same as the others, no particularities), `get_the_category()` return 2 categories instead of one, and the first category of the array is not the good one.

How can I fix this ?

**EDIT :** This is the return array of the `get_the_category()` function :

```
Array
(
    [0] => WP_Term Object
    (
        [term_id] => 152
        [name] => Press
        [slug] => press
        [term_group] => 0
        [term_taxonomy_id] => 152
        [taxonomy] => category
        [description] => Press
        [parent] => 0
        [count] => 46
        [filter] => raw
        [object_id] => 32182
        [cat_ID] => 152
        [category_count] => 46
        [category_description] => Press
        [cat_name] => Press
        [category_nicename] => press
        [category_parent] => 0
    )

[1] => WP_Term Object
    (
        [term_id] => 178
        [name] => The Fundation
        [slug] => the-fundation
        [term_group] => 0
        [term_taxonomy_id] => 178
        [taxonomy] => category
        [description] => 
        [parent] => 0
        [count] => 10
        [filter] => raw
        [object_id] => 32182
        [cat_ID] => 178
        [category_count] => 10
        [category_description] => 
        [cat_name] => The Fundation
        [category_nicename] => the-fundation
        [category_parent] => 0
    )

)
```

I got this for the category page the-fundation

Comment: Done. On the fundation page I've got the press category first, strange isn't it ?

Comment: Its seems you have used multiple category on single post, In that case you can use the first one.

Comment: Well, no, beacause I use get_the_category to get this ID.

Comment: Is that result for the category page or for a post?

Comment: The result is for the category page, I don't have any problem on post page

Comment: try this $categories = get_the_category(); $category_id = $categories[0]->cat_ID;

Comment: Don't you see my result array ? $categories[0]->cat_ID will be 152, and I want the 178 one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
$categories = get_the_category();
$category_id = $categories[0]->cat_ID;
```

or

```
get_query_var('cat');
```

Comment: Thanks, the get_query_var('cat'); solution works fine.

Answer (score 1):

[`get_the_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/) returns an array of `WP_Term` objects (categories) assigned to the current post, it does not return the current category. If you're on a category page it'll default to using the first post within that category.

To get the current category you'd be better off calling [`get_queried_object()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) on the category page:

```
$category = get_queried_object();

if ( $category instanceof WP_Term ) {
    $category_id = $category->term_id;
}
```